# Power BI - I Dont want my card value to change when i select something in slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have sum(value) which is 40000 rs in card visual
but when I select something in slicer my card visual value also changes but obvious because of slicer filter but I don't want that I just want my value to remain 40000 rs only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select you slicers and then edit interaction with your card.
[image]

For each slicer you have to disable filtering on your card.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Lot Friend :) :d

Comment: sorry I have less reputation thus could not answer it as yes